# No module named numpy conda environment

Tags: python, numpy

I have a problem with this error no module found numpy whenever I run a python file on command prompt containing a code import numpy as np. But when I run CMD and run python there, code import numpy, there is no error. I want to be able to run my .py file but I'm stuck with this. I am using conda virtual environment with python 3.6. I've read tutorials about uninstalling and installing again the numpy but nothing works. I've also tried removing other conda environments leaving only one, but still no results.

Answer (score 0):

First try to upgrade pip3 with

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

then You can try installing numpy with this

```
pip3 install numpy
```